# Web UI is loading when configuring Archiva behind Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache2, repository, reverse-proxy

I have setup both `archiva` and `httpd` on `Ubuntu 22.04` for testing.

```
Apache Archiva version: 2.2.9
Apache HTTP Server: 2.4.52
```

**The VirtualHost configuration:**

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ProxyPass "/test/" "http://192.168.1.1:8080/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/test/" "http://192.168.1.1:8080/"
</VirtualHost>
```

**HTTP Server URL**: https://my.example.com/test/
**Archiva Server URL**: http://192.168.1.1:8080/

When using Firefox to open the http://192.168.1.1:8080/ directly, then the whole Archiva UI can show up normally.

When using Firefox to open the https://my.example.com/test/, Firefox can show the `title` as "`Apache Archiva`" but the Web Content not showing up, it only shows the "`Loading`"...

[image]

What's missing in the `VirtualHost` for making the `Archiva` to work with `Reverse Proxy`?

**Update: Here is the view source from Firefox:**

view-source:https://my.example.com/test/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqueryFileTree.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/select2-3.2.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/typeahead.js-bootstrap.0.9.3.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.2.2.2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/archiva.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettify.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sammy.0.7.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/archiva/archiva.js" src="js/require.min.2.1.11.js"></script>

    <title>Apache Archiva</title>

  </head>
...
```

view-source:https://my.example.com/test/js/archiva/archiva.js

```
requirejs(['jquery','jquery.tmpl','jquery.ui','i18n','sammy','startup','utils','domReady!','archiva.main','archiva.cookie-information'], function () {
        loadi18n(function () {
          $.ajax({
            url: "restServices/archivaUiServices/runtimeInfoService/archivaRuntimeInfo/"+usedLang(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){
              window.archivaDevMode=data.devMode;
              window.archivaJavascriptLog=data.javascriptLog;
              window.archivaRuntimeInfo=data;

              window.cookieInformation=mapCookieInformation(data.cookieInformation);

              require(['sammy','jquery','jquery.ui','i18n','jquery.tmpl','archiva.main','utils','domReady!'],function () {
                  startArchivaApplication();
                  $("#loadingDiv").hide();
                  drawQuickSearchAutocomplete();
              })
            }
          })
        });
      });
```

From the `view source`, Firefox can get the correct html content from `Archiva 8080 server`, but it can't activate the js function "`loadi18n`", the "`$("#loadingDiv").hide();`" is not executed at all.

The "`js/archiva/archiva.js`" in `Archiva` can't work as expected in `reverse proxy mode` for `unknown reason`.

Comment: i think you are usinh `https` when you are accessing your web with `https://my.example.com/test/` Are you sure you have `SSL` configuration locally? else try with `http://my.example.com/test/`

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried to disable the https mode in reverse proxy, then the http works on archiva. But I don't understand why https is not working on Archiva. And if I enable both the "https" and "http" mode in reverse proxy mode, when accessing the "http://" mode it will convert to "https" automatically, I also don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerName my.example.com/test/

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile    /path/to/apache_certs/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/apache_certs/cert.key

        ProxyRequests     Off
        ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/
        <Proxy http://localhost:8080/*>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost on
</VirtualHost>
```

Run this command to configure `two apache mods`

```
sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_http
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871001/how-to-setup-apache-archiva-to-use-https-instead-of-http#answer-31113268)

Comment: Thank you, Its the same loading. I found a link says change the Origin header but that link is not using apache2: `http-request set-header Origin http://%[hdr(host)]/`, Do you know how to implement the same thing in apache2? Here is the link: https://wasteofserver.com/apache-archiva-behind-haproxy-with-ssl-termination/

Comment: Check this one https://linuxhostsupport.com/blog/how-to-install-and-configure-haproxy-on-ubuntu-20-04/